Translating mdconfig(8) to Linux
I'm trying to port some scripts from FreeBSD to Linux so that I can share
some management scripts with non-BSD platforms.
One script in particular uses mdconfig, and I haven't yet found any Linux tool that matches its capabilities.
The script is a generalized ZFS pool constructor that can work with either physical or virtual block devices, creating matching GPT partition tables on each device according to a pre-specified schema, naming the partitions by joining the partition type and the device serial number.  So for serial numbers AAAA1111 WXYZJ97 and 7JN52XH19 and partition types EFI, SWAP and ZFS, the three disks will be partitioned identically with partitions named:
EFI-AAAA1111
SWAP-AAAA1111
ZFS-AAAA1111

EFI-WXYZJ97
SWAP-WXYZJ97
ZFS-WXYZJ97

EFI-7JN52XH19
SWAP-7JN52XH19
ZFS-7JN52XH19

and the Zpool will be built from the ZFS-* partitions, depending on how the user lays out the config file that specifies such things.
mdconfig creates a file-, memory- or swap-backed (or even
bit-bucket-backed) block device, which is transparently indistinguishable
from a real hard drive,* or most any other block device (swap
partition, tape drive, etc.), and tools based on FreeBSD's GEOM framework interface seamlessly with either physical or virtual block devices, to query device properties like size, sector count, sector size, device serial number, etc.
# truncate -s10G disk.img
# mdconfig disk.img
md0
# gpart create -s gpt /dev/md0
md0 created
# gpart show -l /dev/md0
=>      40  20971440  md0  GPT  (10G)
        40  20971440       - free -  (10G)

# diskinfo -v /dev/md0
/dev/md0
        512             # sectorsize
        10737418240     # mediasize in bytes (10G)
        20971520        # mediasize in sectors
        0               # stripesize
        0               # stripeoffset
        MD-DEV94492983848663588-INO6048 # Disk ident.
        Yes             # TRIM/UNMAP support
        Unknown         # Rotation rate in RPM

When testing and experimenting, it's frequently convenient to be able to utilize virtual block devices just as though they were physical devices, without requiring a lot of what's and if's and special cases in my code.
The serial number ("Disk ident.") of the drive -- whether physical or virtual -- is pivotal in the naming of the GPT partitions, and the GPT partition names in turn become part of the ZFS vdev structure.  Then if a device fails, I can quickly identify it because the serial number is printed directly on the drive label (and sometimes hand-labeled on the drive tray as well, for hot-swappable backplanes).  While device failure isn't a common scenario with virtual devices, the point is to have flexible tools with a unified interface that don't need to be rewritten when switching from using virtual devices to physical, or indeed, a mix.
So far I have been experimenting with losetup on
Linux.  sfdisk can understand the virtual devices it creates, but hdparm cannot, nor can sdparm.  hdparm is the primary tool I'm aware of that can report a device's serial number on Linux.
# hdparm /dev/loop1

/dev/loop1:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 HDIO_GETGEO failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
# sdparm /dev/loop1
unable to access /dev/loop1, ATA disk?

Lacking access to the serial number, I've been relying on a rather ugly hack to use the GPT UUID:
# $1 is device, what's its serial number?
if freebsd
then # Easy:
    SN="$(
            diskinfo -v "$1" |
            awk '/Disk ident\./ {print $1; exit}'
    )"
else # Not so easy:
    partprobe "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
    udevadm="$(udevadm info "$1")"
    diskinfo="$(
        egrep " ID_SERIAL_SHORT=" <<< $udevadm;
        egrep " ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=" <<< $udevadm
    )"
    SN="$(
        awk -F= '{print $2; exit}' <<< \
           ${diskinfo:-ID_SERIAL_SHORT=UNKNOWN}
    )"
fi

This means many parts of my GPT partitioning script (and others) break
because the script logic expects virtual and physical block devices to function interchangeably, and therefore the script has no need to know whether a device "$d" is a physical or a virtual device.
Other than the multi-step UUID hack above, the biggest workaround I would appreciate would be if there is a way to furnish a string that would establish the serial number of the loop device, and which could be queried by hdparm or some other standard tool, so that I'm not caught over the barrel of having to use two different tools to do one job.
Does losetup have the ability to include a serial number in the loop device's properties, similar to the virtual serial number that FreeBSD's mdconfig creates on md devices?

*: By that I mean that, although strictly speaking, one can distinguish
between the two, I haven't found any FreeBSD tools that work on real drives but
break when used on virtual drives.

what would hdparm do here? are you looking for blockdev?

@frostschutz hdparm is mostly just an example of the problem.  It's one of the many things I tried to use to obtain the things that diskinfo shows: media size, sector size, serial number, etc.... hdparm works on "real" disks, but not on virtual disks.  I'm looking for tools that work equally well on both.  Despite blockdev's man page, my Ubuntu 18 machine errors out on both blockdev --report -v and blockdev -v --report.

losetup creates block devices, not "disks", and that's why tools like hdparm and sdparm -- which are specifically designed to query information on physical disks -- don't work. Loop devices work just fine with tools like [sc]fdisk, parted, etc. Your example blockdev are both syntactically invalid (you can't combine --report and -v), but blockdev --report will correctly show loop devices (and other blockdev commands seem to work just fine as well, e.g., blockdev --getbsz /dev/loop0).

I suggest to explain in your question what you want to achieve with calling hdparm or other tools for physical disks. Maybe the same result could be done using other tools that will work for other block devices. Showing the code of your scripts might also help.

You might try qemu-nbd which uses the nbd Network Block Device driver to emulate disks. I don't know how it responds to hdparm etc.

@larsks Thanks, I was using both in the hopes of getting a verbose report.
